# How to check if a Stream<String> contains another Stream<String> in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I created two Stream

```
Stream<String> first= ...
Stream<String> second= ...
```

Both of them have numbers. Let's say the first file has 1 to 1000 and the second one has 25 to 35. I'd like to check if the first one contains the numbers of the seconds one.

```
first.filter(s-> !s.contains(second.toString())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I replace `second.toString()` with "10" then it works but how can I check the whole stream and not only a char or a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "contains a stream"?  Do you mean that one element from `first` contains each of the strings present in the second?  That each of the elements of second appear somewhere in the first?  What?

Comment: This is not a good use case for `Stream`. If the streams are not infinite (which you can't really check), collect them into `Set`s or `List`s and compare those with `containsAll`.

Comment: I assume you mean "detect which ones of the first one are also in the second?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to collect the `second` stream and store all its values in some adapted data strucutre.

For example using a `Set`:

```
Set<String> secondSet = second.collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<String> f = first.filter(s -> secondSet.contains(s))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Just wondering how costly the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is.

More broadly, is it efficient for `MyClass.getCollection()` to return a stream
in order to allow reading of the collection without writing (outside MyClass).

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        first.add(i.toString());
    }

    for (Integer i = 25; i < 36; i++) {
        second.add(i.toString());
    }   

    boolean result = second.stream().allMatch(
            value -> first.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(value));
```